# ModuleNotFound import script

Tags: python

I'm pretty sure this has been answered before but I can't describe it well enough to find the relevant post (probably not using the correct keywords) so I would love it if you can redirect me to the solution or write it down.

I have a clone of a repo on my local machine which has a folder tree similiar to the following:

```
.
├── Pipes
│   ├── Processing
│   └── Utility
│   ├── Test
│   └── Filtering
```

For example, when I am working on a script under 'Processing' and it includes some import statement of this type: `import Utility.other_script` I get a `ModuleNotFound` error which is totatlly understandable but the question is how do I fix this?
Is it something I have to change in the virtual environment? in the PYTHONPATH? I'm not sure what to look for.

Till now I have used

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'SOME/PATH')
```

But I wish to have a permenant solution so I won't have to type that on every script I am trying to run.

EDIT: Was able to solve this by adding `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/Pipes` to the `.bashrc` file

Comment: `from Pipes.Utility.other_script import *`  this will render all element OR `from Pipes.Utility import other_script`

Comment: @AnupYadav It will work only if `Utility` folder will be a subfolder of the working directory.
If I am in `Processing` it won't detect any folder called `Utility`

Comment: Now check, I've edited comment hope you'll find useful

Comment: @AnupYadav but then I will have to modify the import lines of every script I want to execute. I need a general solution.

Comment: Ok, you wrote `import Utility.other_script` in all files?

Comment: Yeah all of the files include this type of import statements

Comment: Have you added bootstrapping using common file? using `sys` hack though, 
`sys.path.insert(0,'..')` still I don't recommend, your solution will gives issue if multiple projects are deployed at same server / machine. Better to add this using Environment.